# Verify OpenVPN is no longer vulnerable to Heartbleed

Tags: openvpn, heartbleed

As you may know, OpenVPN is vulnerable to the heartbleed attack. However, I can't find any guide online on how to fix it. The only source I've found is this:

http://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/heartbleed

Is just doing (in Ubuntu)

apt-get update; apt-get upgrade; apt-get dist-upgrade

enough to make sure that my OpenVPN is safe? I can confirm i have this version of openSSL:

```
# dpkg-query -l 'openssl'
ii  openssl                                   1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12                         Secure Socket Layer (SSL) binary and related cryptographic tools
```

Thanks

Comment: No, as stated in the wiki article, you also have to rekey everything.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm talking about the exploit itself (i.e. making sure OpenVPN doesn't use a bad openSSL)

Comment: You updated OpenSSL, and restarted all affected services, didn't you?

Comment: `aptitude changelog openssl | grep -B10 CVE-2014-0160`. OK, fixed? Now run `ldd $(which openvpn)` to see which libraries openvpn is using.

Comment: Please do not edit commentary into your post. If you have an issue with post closure in the future open a discussion on [Meta](http://meta.serverfault.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's follow the trail! What does `openvpn` use?

```
$ ldd $(which openvpn)
...
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f464d630000)
```

OK, it's using `libssl.1.0.0` provided by...?

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
libssl1.0.0:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

... provided by `libssl1.0.0`:

```
$ apt-get changelog libssl1.0.0 | grep -B10 CVE-2014-0160

openssl (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12) precise-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: side-channel attack on Montgomery ladder implementation
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0076.patch: add and use constant time swap in
      crypto/bn/bn.h, crypto/bn/bn_lib.c, crypto/ec/ec2_mult.c,
      util/libeay.num.
    - CVE-2014-0076
  * SECURITY UPDATE: memory disclosure in TLS heartbeat extension
    - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0160.patch: use correct lengths in
      ssl/d1_both.c, ssl/t1_lib.c.
    - CVE-2014-0160
```

Looks good to me.

Answer (score -1):

Or execute `openssl version -a` and make sure the build date is April 7th, 2014 or later for affected versions.

Comment: That's not a great solution, because I can compile a vulnerable SSL version today, and versions prior to 1.0.1 weren't vulnerable either.  So this may be better than nothing, but just barely.

Comment: Good point, this is not a thorough enough solution.